# Phoenix Spark Plugin

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, apache-phoenix

is the plugin update to spark 2.0 ?
I can't use the plugin

```
    val df = spark.read
        .format("org.apache.phoenix.spark")
        .option("table", "web_stat")
        .option("zkUrl", "localhost:2181")
        .option("driver","org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver")
        .load()
```

ERROR:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame
```

just jdbc connect phoenix is OK!

when i just use the spark jdbc connector ,it comes

```
val df = spark.read
        .format("jdbc")
        .option("driver", "org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver")
        .option("url", " jdbc:phoenix:localhost:2181")
        .option("dbtable", "web_stat")
        .load()
```

ERROR

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.(JDBCRelation.scala:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:53)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:345)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.phoenix.SparkPhoenixExample$.main(SparkPhoenixExample.scala:65)

Answer (score 0):

Spark 2.0 is not yet working with Phoenix. see this URL for a patch https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PHOENIX-3333